# Likelihood Function for Complicated Transformations

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, approximation

Suppose that data *X* have a Normal distribution with some mean $\mu$ and some variance $\sigma^2$.  However, you don't get to see *X*.  Instead, you see $Y = g(X)$ where $g$ is a known function.  Assume that $g$ is complicated and is not invertible.

How do you write the likelihood function for $Y$?  Or how do you use some numerical method to approximate a likelihood in a way that allows inference about $\mu$ or $\sigma^2$?

Seems like a basic question that has totally stumped me.

Comment: It depends on how smooth $g$ is and whether it is one-to-one.  That landscape can be subdivided into cases where (a) $g$ is differentiable, (b) $g$ is continuous, and (c) $g$ is discontinuous, because the calculations of the likelihoods differ fundamentally among those cases.  Any of our threads on [transforming PDFs](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=transforming+PDF) will apply to (a) when $g$ is one-to-one.

Comment: @whuber The question states that the function g is not invertible. This means that g is not one-to-one.

Comment: This can be very tricky because it can cause complex patterns of non-identifiability in the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$. A *very* simple example is $g(X)=X^2$, for which the sign of $\mu$ cannot be determined. Because of this it is rare to formulate models using non-invertible $g$. Do you have a particular $g$ in mind? (Thanks for clearing up your meaning of "non-invertible": to many readers, noting the context mentions "complicated" and "numerical methods," that would only have meant that *computing* $g^{-1}$ is impracticable.)

Comment: The question is inspired by observed data that come from a known differential equation with unknown parameters.  Inference about the parameters is of interest.  These unknown parameters can be given a known probability distribution with unspecified hyperparameters.  Likelihood inference for the hyperparameters is of interest.  Essentially, $Y = g(X)$, $X \sim N(\theta, \sigma^2)$, all you see is $Y$, find good estimates for the parameters $\theta$ and $\sigma^2$.  Perhaps likelihood methods are not the best approach (but that seems to rule out Bayesian as well).

Comment: That's pretty cool--thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Can you write out the exact equation $Y=g(X)$ please?. Any answer here will critically depend on the exact relation. It is not clear what it means that "observed data come from a known differential equation" -the "come from" part is the unclear one. Are the $Y$'s the values of the _solved_ differential equation as $t$ progresses? Or are they _part_ of the differential equation?

Comment: You might consider looking at "Smearing Estimate: A Nonparametric Retransformaiton Method" by Naihua Duan 1981.  JASA. Volume 78, 1983 - Issue 383.